# On-Heap Caching – MaxSize in Ignite, what it really means?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am bit confused about a parameter "MaxSize" used to configure On-heap caching in Ignite. When considering heap, we always think about the size in terms of memory but I am not sure that’s the case here. Could any one please clarify what is the maxSize Set to 1000000 really means? . The comments above put as 1 million, i.e is kind of number of items for me but that dosn't make much sense for me in the heap.

Here is the link from ignite - https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/on-heap-caching#configuring-eviction-policy

```
 <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheConfiguration">
  <property name="name" value="myCache"/>

  <!-- Enabling on-heap caching for this distributed cache. -->
  <property name="onheapCacheEnabled" value="true"/>

  <property name="evictionPolicy">
    <!-- LRU eviction policy. -->
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.lru.LruEvictionPolicy">
        <!-- Set the maximum cache size to 1 million (default is 100,000). -->
      <property name="maxSize" value="1000000"/>
    </bean>
  </property>

</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's about the number of records in a cache.

This makes sense, since you would like to keep only the most frequently used items for your additional on heap caching

You can use [setMaxMemorySize](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/eviction/AbstractEvictionPolicy.html#setMaxMemorySize-long-) to limit cache size in bytes, just as you described.

Comment: @Alexander - What is the logic to determine the number of records?
For e.g. Cache[“DEPT”] = 1000 departments  ,  Cache[“EMP”] = 10000 employees. I access 2 departments and 100 employees. In this case number of items in heap cache is 2(because I access 2 main cache)  or 102(sub items)?

Comment: It's about your objects, if it's a compound object, it's still one big item. You can think of it in terms of cache keys. If "DEPT" and "EMP" are just keys, then there are only 2 cache items. Internally, Ignite tracks values in Queue and `#getCurrentSize` just returns `queue.sizex()`

Comment: Anyway, it looks like you should have 2 different caches in that config. Eviction policy could be specified individually for every cache. In case of 2 caches, you would end up having 2 for departments and 100 for employees.